# Are ephemeral ports random by default in Windows?

Tags: ports

I'm analyzing a malware and I've noticed that it is doing some form of ephemeral port exhaustion.

**My question:** 
Is it normal for ephemeral ports in a Windows system to be selected in series (i.e. 50001, 50002, 50003, etc) or are they normally random?